# DataFrame index and column as nodes for Networkx

Tags: python, dataframe, networkx

I'm looking to convert a DataFrame to a NetworkX graph: I would like to use the Dataframe as a map where the indexes are the "sources" and the columns are the "targets". The values should be the weights.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'), index = list('ABCD'))
df

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df, source=df.index, target=df.column, create_using=nx.DiGraph
)
```

Here is a example of DataFrame, each index should connect to a column if the value is non-zero.

Would you know how to?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nx.from_pandas_adjacency()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'), index = list('ABCD'))

G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

As the comment form @Huug points out be aware of passing `create_using=nx.DiGraph` to the command, to ensure it is created as a directed graph.

Comment: This is the way, but do also add the DiGraph constructor to the last line like so: `G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph)` to ensure it comes out as a directed graph.